# C++ Unique Class Names vs. Namespace

Tags: c++, json, class, reflection, namespaces

Since C++ doesn't have reflection like Java, I've built a generic set of data containers that can be used for formatting data into various formats (JSON, XML, CSV, etc.). My question is this:

Is it better practice to leave the class names generic and use a namespace, or to make unique class names without a namespace? Also, is this the best way to approach this reflection problem?

For example:

```
namespace FormatContainers
{
    class Object {...};
    class Array {...};
    class Value {...};
}
```

vs

```
class FCObject {...};
class FCArray {...};
class FCValue {...};
```

Example usage of these classes:

```
FCObject o;
o.addNVP("Name1","Value1");
o.addNVP("Name2",5);
cout << o.toString("JSON");
```

yields:

```
{"Name1":"Value1","Name2":5}
```

Comment: From "The Zen of Python": "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!". There should be a "Zen of C ++" too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preference between the two conventions is more of a personal preference.

Prefixing the name is the C style naming conventions to prevent name collisions. Such as in OpenGL all functions are prefixed with `gl`. While this creates unique names, it can end up creating overly long names for functions/structs/classes. Such as `g_file_new_for_commandline_arg_and_cwd` in the GTK+ [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-new-for-commandline-arg-and-cwd) library.

Using namespaces is the C++ way to prevent name collisions. Namespaces combined with using directives allows you to keep names short and to the point without fear of colliding with other names in other namespaces. This is true as long as two namespaces with conflicting names are not imported with using statements into the same scope. Most C++ compilers mangle the names given in the source by prefixing namespace names in a way similar to prefixing in C.

Ambiguous Name:

```
namespace N1 {
    class Test {
    };
}

namespace N2 {
    class Test {
    };
}

using namespace N1;
using namespace N2;

Test t2; // Which Test class should be used?
```

Again neither convention is "better" than the other. It is whichever convention you prefer of whichever one your project guidelines require. In most cases you will see namespaces used in C++ projects and prefixes used in C projects.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `namespace` and create classes in the `namespace`. I see the following advantages of having a `namespace`:

1. It allows you to create classes and functions that don't pollute the global name space.
2. Overloaded function resolution works better when functions defined in a `namespace` have arguments types that are also defined in the same `namespace`.
3. It makes for creation of class names and function names that are clearer. `FormatContainers::Object` is a clearer name than `FCObject`.